# Creating a MYSQL query from results of splitting a string and using LIKE to match keywords in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search, mariadb

I am trying to split a string into an array and use these as keywords to make an sql query. I have made a sample of splitting the array and building the sql query. It sort of works but it is giving every table as a result but when I hard copy the built query it comes up with expected results.

This is what I have so far  -

The string of keywords split into array and the query is built.

The db is called 'clients_personal' and the table is called 'likes'

```
$my_search = "paper, glue, discount, bulk";
$new_search = preg_split("/,/", $my_search);
$mmsql = "SELECT * FROM clients_personal WHERE likes LIKE '%offers%'";

foreach ($new_search as $value) {
  $mmsql = $mmsql." OR likes LIKE '%$value%'";
}
```

No that results something like :

```
$mmsql="SELECT * FROM clients_personal WHERE likes LIKE '%offers%' OR likes LIKE '%paper%' OR likes LIKE '%glue%' OR likes LIKE '%discount%' OR likes LIKE '%bulk%'";
```

Now if I search like this, I get all the rows in the db?

```
$sql = "$mmsql";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id=$row["id"];

echo $id;
}
}
```

But if I query is as hard coded it gives predicted results?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients_personal WHERE likes LIKE '%offers%' OR likes LIKE '%paper%' OR likes LIKE '%glue%' OR likes LIKE '%discount%' OR likes LIKE '%bulk%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

I have a feeling its to do with quotes and i have tried removing them but no good? Any advice?
Also I an using this type of search as I found it on here.

Comment: May be yuo compare both strings to find diff by yourself

Comment: I have done that? I have echoed it out, I am not asking anyone to do it for me, simply and If doing it wrong completely!

Comment: in mmsql `% glue%` (with space) and so on

Comment: Try `trim($value)` inside of your loop before you add it to the string.

Comment: I cant see any spaces anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `$new_search = preg_split("/,/", $my_search);` use `$new_search = preg_split("/, /", $my_search);` instead.

The items in the string are separated by a comma and a space (", ") so you should split the string with that.

Comment: Ye cheers, your all correct, thanks